# How to remove focus from textarea when it is in active use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the textarea is in active use (meaning, a user is typing keystores in this field), if the  sequence of characters being typed matches a defined sequence like "aeu" then, I would like to **set focus out of the textarea and click a button**.

**Note**: I am using the Mousetrap plugin to handle keyboard shortcuts.
https://github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap/blob/master/mousetrap.min.js

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/PqXWJ/5/

As you can see in the demo page, I have tried `blur()` and `trigger('blur')` but, I wasn't able to remove focus out of the textarea.

Comment: blur should get the job done. What's happening is the mouseTrap plugin isn't catching the keystrokes.

Comment: The mousetrap plugin works fine when the focus is not on the textarea.

Comment: Right. while focus is on the textarea, keypress keyup and keydown events aren't reaching the document which is a requirement for the Mousetrap plugin to function.

Comment: So, do you have any suggestions? also, I can skip the mousetrap plugin if I can handle - detecting a combination of keystores by other means.

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong. There's a bug somewhere in the mousetrap that's causing it to reset the current sequence on each keypress when in a textarea. I would just not use the plugin and roll my own. http://jsfiddle.net/PqXWJ/18/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what that library you are using is but I got the functionality you wanted using some simple jQuery event binding.

```
$('#text').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === 'aeu') $(this).blur();
    $('#myBtnId').click();
});
```

Here is an example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TfWAq/).

UPDATE:

Here is a reworked example using a text area and allowing for any number of characters to be entered before the desired string.  [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RqH9H/)

UPDATE 2:

Added the button functionality you requested.  Cheers!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VZewJ/)

Comment: It's a start but not exactly what I am looking for. Textarea is different from a text input field. In my case, (textarea), I guess I should modify your code to check if the textarea contains the string "aeu" ..

Comment: This code should work with any input type.  You can certainly make your selection more specific with the use of string parsing or regular expressions.

Comment: Please see edited answer.  I think it addresses your concerns.

Comment: @chockleyc Your updated example is missing the button `#myBtnId` that gets clicked when aeu detected. Perhaps you specified an incorrect URL? I quickly added it [here - http://jsfiddle.net/RqH9H/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/RqH9H/1/) and it seems to click the button with each keystroke.

Comment: My apologies I had left the button up to you.  I fixed the code in a final update.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without plugin -

```
$('textarea').on('keyup', function () {
    if (this.value === 'enter') {
        $(this).blur();
    }
});
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/PqXWJ/5/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you might be looking for

```
<textarea id="upcinput"></textarea>
<p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will un <a id="exception-btn">click here</a></p>

$('#upcinput').keyup(function () {
 if ($(this).val() === 'lorem ipsum') { 
    $(this).blur();
    $('#exception-btn').click();
 }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZYJxq/4/

Answer (score 0):

The mousetrap plugin you are using seems to have a bug with textareas, though since this is such an easy task, it would be quicker to roll my own than fix the broken plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/PqXWJ/18/

```
var sequence = [], targetsequence = [65,69,85,13];
$(document).on("keyup",function(e) {
    if (e.which == targetsequence[sequence.length]) {
        sequence.push(e.which);
        if (sequence.length == targetsequence.length) {
            alert("Correct Sequence!");
            $("#upcinput").blur();
            sequence = [];
        }
    }
    else {
        sequence = [];
    }
});
```